# c++ member function above member field

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

When I run the following code:

```
class Worker : public Thread{

private:
    void readData(WorkItem *item, std::vector<DataPoint> &mt);

    wqueue<WorkItem*>& queue;
    ReqParser* reqParser;
public:
    Worker(wqueue<WorkItem*>& queue, DatabaseService* db_service);
    void* run();
};


Worker::Worker(wqueue<WorkItem*>& queue): m_queue(queue)  {
    reqParser = new SdkReqParser();
}

void* Worker::run() {
    std::vector<DataPoint> peaks;

    while(true) {
        WorkItem* item = NULL;
        item = queue.remove();
        peaks.clear();
        readData(item, peaks);

        /**
        the rest of logic never touching reqParser
        **/
    }
}

void Worker::readData(WorkItem *item, std::vector<DataPoint> &mt){
    printf("readData: %p\n", reqParser);
    fflush(stdout);
    reqParser->parse(item->getReq(), item->getReqSize(), item, mt);
}
```

After some time of successful execution I am getting SIGSEGV from method readData. Right before the segmentation fault occurs the address of reqParser pointer changes. No destructor is invoked, reqParser is never assigned outside constructor which is called once per program.

Changing the order of members in class definition and moving readData method below reqParser seems to solve the problem. I do not understand why and I am not sure if it is the real solution.

```
class Worker : public Thread{

private:
    wqueue<WorkItem*>& m_queue;
    ReqParser* reqParser;

    void readData(WorkItem *item, std::vector<DataPoint> &mt);
public:
    Worker(wqueue<WorkItem*>& queue, DatabaseService* db_service);
    void* run();
};
```

Comment: Something somewhere in your code has undefined behaviour. It's pretty much impossible to guess what or where.

Comment: You probably have a stray pointer somewhere. Try running your program under valgrind, it sometimes picks up dodgy memory accesses.

Comment: After removing all Valgrind reported errors SIGSEGV is gone.